# Convert whitepspaces in selects to nbsp;

Tags: jsf-2, tags

I have a select:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="treeNode" label="#{msgs.treeNode}" value="#{treeNode}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{treeItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

which uses these selectItems:

```
List<SelectItem> treeItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("1", "Parent"));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("2", "  Child 0 0"));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("2", "    Child 0 0 0"));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("2", "    Child 0 0 1"));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("2", "  Child 0 1"));
```

My problem is that the output in the select should look like a tree, but since the whitspaces are gone I have a "flat"-view.

Is there a way how I could convert the whitspaces into a nonbreakable-space?

Thanks
Jonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace them by `&nbsp;` yourself and set the `escape` attribute to `false`. It's the 5th argument of the `SelectItem` constructor.

```
List<SelectItem> treeItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("1", "Parent", null, false, false));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("2", "&nbsp;&nbsp;Child 0 0", null, false, false));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("3", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Child 0 0 0", null, false, false));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("4", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Child 0 0 1", null, false, false));
treeItems.add(new SelectItem("5", "&nbsp;&nbsp;Child 0 1", null, false, false));
```

Comment: Sorry Balus, I entered before I was finished writing. Here the case:  But there's a big flaw in this solution. User can edit this tree (not in my application) and can enter whatever names they want. This could lead to an Cross-Site-Scripting vulnerability in my app. Any suggestions?  Thnaks  Jonny

Comment: Use a HTML parser to remove all unwanted markup. For example Jsoup:  http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll give it a try. Jonny

Comment: By the way: I'm using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()-method from the commons-lang3 package for escaping now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put a foreach, after the last treeItem is added, that iterates through each SelectItem and replace each empty string " " with "`&nbsp;`"?